# use facebook javascript SDK Graph API in QML?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml

I need  to use facebook Grah API in a native mobile application in Qt using QML? is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript in QML. see [Integrating JavaScript](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdeclarativejavascript.html)

To make network requests to the FB API, use the [`XMLHttpRequest`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdeclarativeglobalobject.html#xmlhttprequest) api.

Comment: Hi Actually I am using qfacebook (http://gitorious.org/qfacebook) but all I want is to get the access token after login to use it in my application to get friends,likes,photos...

Comment: And it didn't happen to you that this could have been interesting  informations to add to your question, did it? Just ask the qfacebook developers.